# MPI Scatterv error there is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_scatterv

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I am trying to run this code, the error says 'there is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_scatterv'

```
program mpiscatterv
!implicit none
use mpi
real, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: r, rcv_buf
integer :: ierr, my_id, n_proc, rcv_id, snd_id, counter
integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: sendcounts, displs, rcv_count
integer, parameter :: master = 0
integer :: i,j,k
integer :: n = 0
integer :: ios_read = 0
integer :: rem ! remaining data 
integer :: div
integer :: summ = 0




open (unit=99, file ='datatest1.dat',iostat=ios_read)
if (ios_read /=0) then
        print*, 'could not be opened'
end if

!open (unit=99, file='rawdata2.dat',iostat=ios_read)
do
  read (99, *, iostat=ios_read) i,x,y

    if (ios_read > 0) then
        print*,'something is wrong'
        print*,ios_read
        stop
   else if (ios_read < 0) then
        print*, 'end of file is reached'
        exit
   else
        n = n+1
   end if
end do
rewind(99)
open(unit=98, file='rawdata2.dat')
allocate(r(2,n))

do i=1,n
read(99,*, iostat=ios_read)j,x,y
r(1,j)= x
r(2,j)= y
write (98,*) x, y
end do

close (99)
close (98)

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, my_id, ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, n_proc, ierr)

rem = mod(2*n,n_proc)

allocate (sendcounts(n_proc))
allocate (displs(n_proc))
allocate (rcv_count(n_proc))
allocate (rcv_buf(2,n_proc))


counter = 1

do while (counter<=n_proc)
sendcounts(counter) = int(2*n/n_proc)
  if (rem > 0) then
      sendcounts(counter)=int(2*n/n_proc)+2
    rem = rem-2
  end if
rcv_count=sendcounts
displs(counter)=summ
summ=summ+sendcounts(counter)
counter = counter + 1
end do

counter = 1
if (my_id==0) then
   do while (counter<n_proc)
     print*,sendcounts, displs
     counter = counter + 1
   end do
end if


call MPI_Scatterv(r,sendcounts,displs,mpi_real,rcv_buf,rcv_count,mpi_real,0,mpi_comm_world,ierr)

call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program
```

I have r data that I want to scatter. r is a 2 coumns and n row. I use scatterv because the data is not divisable by n_proc. When I want to compile it, it shows error, as far as I concern I already do it according to the limited guidance that I got from internet, any website. Which parameter is wrong ?

Comment: `rcv_count` should be a scalar, not an array.

Comment: I'd also uncomment `Implicit None` - it is there to help you

Comment: I would include information on what compiler you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. I managed to reproduce your error by trying to compile your code (`main.f90`) with gfortran v6.3 and openMPI v3.1.4

```
mpifort main.f90                                                                         
test3.f90:85:106:                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                            
 call MPI_Scatterv(r(1,:),sendcounts,displs,mpi_real,rcv_buf(1,:),rcv_count,mpi_real,0,mpi_comm_world,ierr)                                 
                                                                                                          1                                 
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_scatterv’ at (1)
```

On openMPI's website you can see that `MPI_Scatterv` requires the following:

```
Input Parameters

sendbuf
    Address of send buffer (choice, significant only at root). 
sendcounts
    Integer array (of length group size) specifying the number of elements to send to each processor. 
displs
    Integer array (of length group size). Entry i specifies the displacement (relative to sendbuf) from which to take the outgoing data to process i. 
sendtype
    Datatype of send buffer elements (handle). 
recvcount
    Number of elements in receive buffer (integer). 
recvtype
    Datatype of receive buffer elements (handle). 
root
    Rank of sending process (integer). 
comm
    Communicator (handle).
```

The problems is `recvcount` (or in your case `rcv_count`) should just be a single integer.

I should point out there are several other issues you should address:

- As suggested by others you should uncomment `implicit none`
- `x` and `y` will be undefined when you do this
- You really should avoid sending N-dimensional arrays in MPI
- Your `rcv_buf` is almost certainly the wrong size. I think it should be `n/n_proc` at least.

The following code compiles, but you need to check carefully. It probably doesn't work.

```
program mpiscatterv
  use mpi
  implicit none
  real, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: r, rcv_buf
  integer :: ierr, my_id, n_proc, rcv_id, snd_id, counter
  integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: sendcounts, displs
  integer, parameter :: master = 0
  integer :: i,j,k, rcv_count
  real    :: x, y
  integer :: n = 0
  integer :: ios_read = 0
  integer :: rem ! remaining data 
  integer :: div
  integer :: summ = 0

  open (unit=99, file ='datatest1.dat',iostat=ios_read)
  if (ios_read /=0) then
    print*, 'could not be opened'
  end if

  !open (unit=99, file='rawdata2.dat',iostat=ios_read)
  do
    read (99, *, iostat=ios_read) i,x,y

    if (ios_read > 0) then
      print*,'something is wrong'
      print*,ios_read
      stop
    else if (ios_read < 0) then
      print*, 'end of file is reached'
      exit
    else
      n = n+1
    end if
  end do
  rewind(99)
  open(unit=98, file='rawdata2.dat')
  allocate(r(2,n))

  do i=1,n
    read(99,*, iostat=ios_read)j,x,y
    r(1,j)= x
    r(2,j)= y
    write (98,*) x, y
  end do

  close (99)
  close (98)

  call mpi_init(ierr)
  call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, my_id, ierr)
  call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, n_proc, ierr)

  rem = mod(2*n,n_proc)

  allocate (sendcounts(n_proc))
  allocate (displs(n_proc))
  allocate (rcv_buf(2,n/n_proc))


  counter = 1

  do while (counter<=n_proc)
    sendcounts(counter) = int(2*n/n_proc)
    if (rem > 0) then
      sendcounts(counter)=int(2*n/n_proc)+2
      rem = rem-2
    end if
    displs(counter)=summ
    summ=summ+sendcounts(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
  end do

  counter = 1
  if (my_id==0) then
    do while (counter<n_proc)
      print*,sendcounts, displs
      counter = counter + 1
    end do
  end if


  call MPI_Scatterv(r(1,:),sendcounts,displs,mpi_real,rcv_buf(1,:),rcv_count,mpi_real,0,mpi_comm_world,ierr)

  call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program
```